# python find minimum value in dictionary iteratively

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary (named distances) which looks like this :

```
{0: {0: 122.97560733739029, 1: 208.76062847194152, 2: 34.713109915419565}, 1: {0: 84.463009655114703, 1: 20.83266665599966, 2: 237.6299644405141}, 2: {0: 27.018512172212592, 1: 104.38390680559911, 2: 137.70257804413103}}
```

Now, what I need to do is I have to find the minimum value corresponding to each key and then store its index separately. I have written this code for that :

```
weights_indexes = {}    
for index1 in distances:
    min_dist = min(distances[index1], key=distances[index1].get)
    weights_indexes[index1] = min_dist
```

The output for this, looks like :

```
{0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 0}
```

Now, the issue is this that indexes should always be unique. Lets say that now if we have a dictionary like :

```
{0: {0: 34.713109915419565, 1: 208.76062847194152, 2: 122.97560733739029}, 1: {0: 84.463009655114703, 1: 20.83266665599966, 2: 237.6299644405141}, 2: {0: 27.018512172212592, 1: 104.38390680559911, 2: 137.70257804413103}}
```

so, the output of finding minimum indexes for this will be :

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0}
```

Here, the indexes (values) obtained are not unique. In this scenario, the values corresponding to the indexes where duplicates are found have to be compared. So, 34.713109915419565 and 27.018512172212592 will be compared. Since 27.018512172212592 is smaller, so its index will be picked. And for the index 0, mapping will be done to next smallest index, that is index of 122.97560733739029. So, final mapping will look like :

```
    {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 0}
```

This should happen iteratively unless, all the values are unique.
I am not able to figure out how to check for uniqueness and the iteratively keep finding the next minimum one to make the mapping.

Comment: You may want to consider a different data structure that makes it easier to solve whatever you're ultimately trying to do. For example, given that your keys (inner and outer) are integers, sequential, start at 0, and all inner dicts have the same length, a (numpy) 2D array could be an alternative that perhaps can help you out.

Comment: why not use tuple ?
weights_indexes = []
weights_indexes.append(( index1, min_dist))

Comment: okay. even after I use tuple or numpy array, how will I iteratively keep finding the next minimum unless all the values in weighted_indexes are unique?
Also, the distances are there in dictionary format and I cannot change that. I only have control over weighted_indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workable solution:

```
test = {0: {0: 12.33334444, 1: 208.76062847194152, 2: 34.713109915419565}, 1: {0: 84.463009655114703, 1: 20.83266665599966, 2: 237.6299644405141}, 2: {0: 27.018512172212592, 1: 104.38390680559911, 2: 137.70257804413103}}

sorted_index_map = {}

for key, value in test.iteritems():
    sorted_index_map[key] = sorted(value, key=lambda k: value[k])

index_of_min_index_map = {key: 0 for key in test}

need_to_check_duplicate = True

while need_to_check_duplicate:
    need_to_check_duplicate = False
    min_index_map = {key: sorted_index_map[key][i] for key, i in index_of_min_index_map.iteritems()}
    index_set = list(min_index_map.itervalues())
    for key, index in min_index_map.iteritems():
        if index_set.count(index) == 1:
            continue
        else:
            for key_to_check, index_to_check in min_index_map.iteritems():
                if key != key_to_check and index == index_to_check:
                    if test[key][index] > test[key_to_check][index_to_check]:
                        index_of_min_index_map[key] += 1
                        need_to_check_duplicate = True
                        break

result = {key: sorted_index_map[key][i] for key, i in index_of_min_index_map.iteritems()}
print result
```

The result:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Break down:
First sort the indexes by it's value:

```
test = {0: {0: 12.33334444, 1: 208.76062847194152, 2: 34.713109915419565}, 1: {0: 84.463009655114703, 1: 20.83266665599966, 2: 237.6299644405141}, 2: {0: 27.018512172212592, 1: 104.38390680559911, 2: 137.70257804413103}}

sorted_index_map = {}

for key, value in test.iteritems():
sorted_index_map[key] = sorted(value, key=lambda k: value[k])
```

Then for each key the min value's index is the first number in the `sorted_index_map`:

```
index_of_min_index_map = {key: 0 for key in test}
```

Now we need to check if there are any duplicate indexes, if there are, for all the value's of the same index that are not the smallest. we shift to the next small index, i.e. the next one in the `sorted_index_map` of the key. If there are non duplicate, we're done.

```
need_to_check_duplicate = True

while need_to_check_duplicate:
    need_to_check_duplicate = False
    min_index_map = {key: sorted_index_map[key][i] for key, i in index_of_min_index_map.iteritems()}
    index_set = list(min_index_map.itervalues())
    for key, index in min_index_map.iteritems():
        if index_set.count(index) == 1:
            continue
        else:
            for key_to_check, index_to_check in min_index_map.iteritems():
                if key != key_to_check and index == index_to_check:
                    if test[key][index] > test[key_to_check][index_to_check]:
                        index_of_min_index_map[key] += 1
                        need_to_check_duplicate = True
                        break
```

Note you haven't mentioned how to handle the index if there are two identical value so I assume there won't be.

Comment: The solution is working only if one step iteration is there. It is not working for this test data :
test = {0: {0: 12.33334444, 1: 208.76062847194152, 2: 34.713109915419565}, 1: {0: 84.463009655114703, 1: 20.83266665599966, 2: 237.6299644405141}, 2: {0: 27.018512172212592, 1: 104.38390680559911, 2: 137.70257804413103}}
result = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}
whereas, it should be :
result = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}

Comment: @meemee: I've fixed a bug in my answer. Have a test now?

Comment: @meemee: Glad it's working. Also this is a pretty simple solution. If you care about efficiency you should look for a better solution.